# pcl down sampling and filtering - retaining width and height (organized cloud)

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to retain width and height (organized cloud) after doing some operations with PCL library?
I am doing down sampling with VoxelGrid and then PassThrough filtering. In every step I loose width and height data and get unorganized Point Cloud eventhough I start with organized cloud from Kinect.

Thank you for help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33802/pcl-down-sampling-and-filtering---retaining-width-and-height-(organized-cloud)/) by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 460 on 2012-05-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In many cases retaining the original 2D structure is not possible.

In detail, the answer depends on exactly what operations are performed.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1